# Keeping UserControl in memory

Tags: c#, wpf

My application is a window with a main grid which will contain my pages (the User Controls).

I want to be able to navigate in the history of the previous user controls displayed.

That's why I'm storing in the memory the last 30 user control displayed. My code looks like this when displaying a new UC :

```
MyHistoryPage page = new MyHistoryPage();
page.AssociatedUC = (UserControl)this.mainGrid.Children[0];
this.mainGrid.Children.Clear();
this.mainGrid.Children.Add(new MyCustomUC());
```

All my "MyHistoryPage" are stored in a static list.

This works great, I'm able to get the previous Ucs in the same state (same sort, same checkboxes checked, same scroll, same tab selected etc.) and give the user a good experience.

However it seems to cause memory leaks or at least it seems to slow down my application. The mouse over effects are becoming slower and slower.

Dot Memory obviously tells me that the memory used has become bigger.

Is it good to store a lot of UI components in the memory to use them later ? What would be a better solution to manage history and have my UCs in the same state ?

Comment: Maybe you can serialize and deserialize you controls.

Answer (score -1):

What about trying to migrate your application to a MVVM pattern?

The ViewModels are not recreated everytime you access to a previous userControl, so the state could be the same and you will not have memory issues.

If you are not used to work with this pattern you can use many of the available toolkits to start like MVVM Light, Caliburn.Micro, ...